# Поиск позиции в при запросе

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте.

Имеется таблица пользователей

```
id | login | point
------------------
1  | Name1 | 10 
---------------
2  | Name2 | 20
---------------
3  | Name3 | 25
---------------
4  | Name4 | 50
---------------
```

- id - идентификатор, int
- login - логин пользователя, varchar
- point - монеты, int

Задача - одним запросом получить порядковый номер строки на, которой находится пользователь при сортировке по point и получении в обратном порядке.

Например, при

```
SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY point DESC;
```

получаем список, где пользователь с id=2 будет на третьей строке. Тем самым одним запросом нужно получить порядковый номер, без вывода списка.

Comment: А что такое порядковый номер строки ? И какая от него польза ?

Comment: @shurik видимо речь про рейтинги

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET @pos:=0;
SELECT `position` FROM (SELECT `id`,@pos:=@pos+1 as `position` FROM `users` ORDER BY `point` DESC) as positioned WHERE `id` = 3
```

Comment: SET @pos:=0;
SELECT @pos:=@pos+1 FROM `users` ORDER BY `point` DESC

Этого достаточно

Comment: Photon, уверены? Ваш запрос:

    SET @pos:=0; SELECT @pos:=@pos+1 FROM users ORDER BY point DESC

выведет один столбик, где будут числа от 1 до n, где n количество записей таблицы

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT U.id
     , U.name
     , U.point
     , count(DISTINCT U2.id)
     , count(DISTINCT U3.id)
FROM
  users U
LEFT OUTER JOIN users U2
ON U2.`point` <= U.point
LEFT OUTER JOIN users U3
ON U3.`point` >= U.point
GROUP BY
  U.id
, U.name
, U.point;
```